# Locking mechanism for synchronization between multiple threads

Tags: multithreading

I have a scenario where i am spawning multiple threads (each of them working on a browser instance). But all threads share 1 common operation which i need to synchronize. I was thinking of creating locks using file created on disk, but am afraid will that really work ?

Basically i need some locking mechanism on windows platform. I am spawning multiple threads, each thread is an automated script (javascript/batch) working over browser, but i need to synchronise any operation which triggers opening of save as/upload dialog in browser.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Depends strongly on the language, platform, OS, etc you want to develop on.

For POSIX you could achieve that e.g. with mutexes:
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_mutex_lock.html

If you develop with C++17:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex

Regarding your question: you could also do that with file locks. In that case you would have to wait for the file to be locked again, which can be achieved with `select()`

Comment: I am working on windows platform. I dont' have use any language as such (like c++, java). I am simply triggering multiple threads using a exe. each thread is invoking my automated script working over browser instance.

Comment: can you share one very simple example which uses lock to synchronize any simple task. Just for quicker understanding

Comment: @n00ne what C++17 has to do with the mutes that is available (as stated by your link) since C++11.

Comment: @linuxuserHow do you spawn multiple threads? Are you sure you are not confusing process (which is launched by each .exe invocation) with the concept of threads?

Comment: @DanM. No the exe invokes multiple threads/browsers. The exe is invoked only once.

Comment: @linuxuser in what languge is the exe written? Do you have access to its source code? If not, when how do you intent to change it's functionality in any way? You need to be able to modify exe/scripts source code to add any synchronization that was not present before.

Comment: @DanM. ok so exe is invoking multiple scripts (each script operates on an individual browser) all these scripts internally uses a file which is written in custom dsl. I can execute javascript or windows batch commands inside this dsl file. There is 1 operation inside this dsl file which when invoked via multiple scripts needs to be synchronized. The framework i use for dsl file does not support any synchronization. So i need to write my own synchronization/locking mechanism to achieve atomic execution of my operation.

Comment: for example i though of achieving locking mechanism by creating locks using files on hard disk. each thread before performing the operation will check if the file lock exists. But i am afraid such file level lock creation will not be robust synchronization logic.

Comment: Since i can execute batch or windows commands, So are there any other mechanism in windows command prompt which allows to synchronize an execution of some operation. I can understand my question is still bit abstract, i cant share much details on it too either, just explain me if there is any way to do synchronization at windows command level. I will then figure out if its apt in my use case.

Comment: In that case it seems that file locking is the only viable solution for you: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_locking (not sure how much control you have other the threads/scripts, so not sure how robust you could make it but it should be possible)